# kube-proxy is permanently down

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Kube-proxy can't be started anymore on GKE: `Init:ImagePullBackOff`.

When I try to pull:

```
docker pull busybox
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
03b1be98f3f9: Already exists 
error pulling image configuration: unknown blob
```

Comment: Have you tried manually deleting the images that docker has cached locally?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Not had a chance to try removing it from cache yet

Comment: upon my return, the issue had been resolved, without any interference from me. Unsure why... could the cache have been expired? Wreaked havoc with my prom instance that happened to be running on the same node..

Comment: I forgot I head this topic open, in the end a problem with the Google Container Registry and the mirror GKE uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an outage on Oct 12 that is caused by an image caching issue on   Google Container Registry that impacted the `kube-proxy` image indirectly. The issue was fixed later on that day.